# Returning the minimum value in a JSON array

Tags: python, json

Good evening folks! I have been wracking my brain on this one for a good few hours now and could do with a little bit of a pointer in the right direction. I'm playing around with some API calls and trying to make a little project for myself.

The JSON data is stored in Arrays, and as such to get the information I want (it is from a Transport API) I have been making the following

```
x = apirequest
x = x.json


for i in range(0,4):
    print(x['routes'][i]['duration'])
    print(x['routes'][i]['departure_time'])  
    print(x['routes'][i]['arrival_time'])
```

This will return the following

```
06:58:00
23:39
06:37
05:08:00
05:14
10:22
03:41:00
05:30
09:11
03:47:00
06:24
10:11
```

What I am trying to do, is return only the shortest journeys - I could do it if it was a single layer JSON string but I am not too familliar with multi-level arrays. I can't return ['duration'] without utilising ['routes'] and route indicator (in this case 0 through 3 or 4).

I can use an if statement to iterate through them easily enough, but there must be a way to accomplish it directly through the JSON that I am missing. I also thought about adding the results to a separate array and then filtering that - but there is a few other fields I want to grab from the data when I've cracked this part.

What I am finding as I learn is that I tend to do things a long winded way, often finding out my 10-15 line solutions on codewars are actually aimed at being done in 2-3 lines.

Example JSON data

```
{
    "request_time": "2018-05-29T19:03:04+01:00",
    "source": "Traveline southeast journey planning API",
    "acknowledgements": "Traveline southeast",
    "routes": [{
        "duration": "06:58:00",
        "route_parts": [{
            "mode": "foot",
            "from_point_name": "Corunna Court, Wrexham",
            "to_point_name": "Wrexham General Rail Station",
            "destination": "",
            "line_name": "",
            "duration": "00:36:00",
            "departure_time": "23:39",
            "arrival_time": "00:15"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Hope you can help steer me in the right direction!

Comment: I hope these lines are just for tests: `y = json.dumps(z.json());
x = json.loads(y)`

Comment: Can we get an example of the json data?

Comment: A general observation: There is no such thing as a JSON array (or -object). There are arrays and there is JSON. JSON is a string. A string that you can porentially turn into an array by parsing it, but then it's not JSON anymore.

Comment: That being said - `json.dumps(z.json())` looks suspiciously like double-encoding. If `z.json()` returns JSON, then you should not feed it through `json.dumps()` once more. If `z.json()` does not return JSON then it should get a better name.

Comment: @MegaIng added some JSON data for you, after that it is the other routes and actual co-ordinates, the file itself is massive (~200kb)

Comment: Also re the double encoding, you're probably right - this is me muddling through with random googling thus far

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using `datetime.timedelta`. Data from @fferri.

```
from datetime import timedelta

x = {'routes': [{'duration':'06:58:00','departure_time':'23:39','arrival_time':'06:37'},
                {'duration':'05:08:00','departure_time':'05:14','arrival_time':'10:22'},
                {'duration':'03:41:00','departure_time':'05:30','arrival_time':'09:11'},
                {'duration':'03:47:00','departure_time':'06:24','arrival_time':'10:11'}]}

def minimum_time(k):
    h, m, s = map(int, x['routes'][k]['duration'].split(':'))
    return timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)

res = min(range(4), key=minimum_time)  # 2
```

You can then access the appropriate sub-dictionary via `x['routes'][res]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `min()` with a `key` argument to indicate which field should be used for finding the minimum value:

```
x={'routes':[
    {'duration':'06:58:00','departure_time':'23:39','arrival_time':'06:37'},
    {'duration':'05:08:00','departure_time':'05:14','arrival_time':'10:22'},
    {'duration':'03:41:00','departure_time':'05:30','arrival_time':'09:11'},
    {'duration':'03:47:00','departure_time':'06:24','arrival_time':'10:11'}
]}

best=min(x['routes'], key=lambda d: d['duration'])
# best={'duration': '03:41:00', 'departure_time': '05:30', 'arrival_time': '09:11'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The min(iterable, key=...) function is what you are looking for:

```
x = { 'routes': [ {'dur':3, 'depart':1, 'arrive':4},
                  {'dur':2, 'depart':2, 'arrive':4}]}
min(x['routes'], key=lambda item: item['dur'])
```

Returns:

```
{'dur': 2, 'depart': 2, 'arrive': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the fact that `x` is initialized from JSON isn't particularly relevant. It's a `dict`, and that's all that is important.

To answer your question, you just need the `key` attribute to `min`:

```
shortest = min(x['routes'], key=lambda d: d['duration'])
```